# Need help resizing an image grid with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid-layout

I'm working on my portfolio and i can't figure out to set my grid to 100% width. I'm trying to make the grid flush with the top, bottom, and sides. You can see how it looks now here:

[Current Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNI0J.jpg)

And then this is the way i'm trying to make it look:

[Mockup Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwhCD.jpg)

Here's the original code

```js
/**
 * jQuery Expanding Grid plugin.
 *
 * By Dan Boulet - https://danboulet.com
 */
(function ($, window, document) {

// Enable strict mode
"use strict";

/**
 * Return the last element in the current row of a grid layout.
 */
var getLastSiblingInRow = function (element) {
 var candidate = element,
   elementTop = element.offsetTop;

 // Loop through the element’s next siblings and look for the first one which
 // is positioned further down the page.
 while (candidate.nextElementSibling !== null) {
  if (candidate.nextElementSibling.offsetTop > elementTop) {
   return candidate;
  }
  candidate = candidate.nextElementSibling;
 }
 return candidate;
};

/**
 * Calculate the distance that we need to scroll the page to bring a
 * section, defined as the area between the top and bottom, into view.
 */
var calculatePageScrollDistance = function (top, bottom) {
 var windowScrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop(),
   windowHeight = $(window).height(),
   scrollDistanceToTop,
   scrollDistanceToBottom;

 // Scroll to the top of the section if the we are already scrolled past it.
 if (windowScrollDistance >= top) {
  return top - windowScrollDistance;
 }
 // Do nothing if there is enough space to show the section without having to scroll.
 else if ((windowScrollDistance + windowHeight) >= bottom) {
  return 0;
 }
 else {
  // Find the maximum distance we can scroll without passing the top of the section.
  scrollDistanceToTop = top - windowScrollDistance;
  // Find the distance we need to scroll to reveal the entire section.
  scrollDistanceToBottom = bottom - (windowScrollDistance + windowHeight);

  return Math.min(scrollDistanceToTop, scrollDistanceToBottom);
 }
};

/**
 * Create the expanding preview grid.
 */
var expandingGrid = function (context, options) {
 var defaults = {
  animationDuration: 250,
  linksSelector: '.links a',
  expandingAreaSelector: '.expanding-container',
  closeButtonMarkup: '<a href="#" class="close-button">Close</a>',
  spacerMarkup: '<span class="spacer" aria-hidden="true"/>',
  elementActiveClass: 'active',
  elementExpandedClass: 'expanded',
  onExpandBefore: false,
  onExpandAfter: false
 };

 var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

 var isExpanded = false;
 var activeLink = false;
 var activeExpandedArea = false;
 var activeExpandedAreaTop = false;
 var activeExpandedAreaHeight = false;
 var lastItemInActiveRow = false;
 var activeRowChanged = false;
 var checkExpandedAreaResize = false;
 var $links = $(settings.linksSelector, context);
 var $expandingAreas = $(settings.expandingAreaSelector, context);
 var $closeButton = $(settings.closeButtonMarkup);
 var $spacer = $(settings.spacerMarkup);
 var $secondarySpacer = $spacer.clone();

 /**
  * Scroll a section of the page into view, using animation.
  */
 var scrollSectionIntoView = function (top, bottom, duration, callback) {
  var animate;
  var scroll = 0;
  var distance = calculatePageScrollDistance(top, bottom);
  var windowScrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();
  var timeLeft;

  // Set default duration.
  duration = (typeof duration === 'undefined') ? settings.animationDuration : duration;
  timeLeft = duration;

  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var last = start;
  var tick = function() {
   timeLeft = Math.max(duration - (new Date() - start), 0);

   var x = (timeLeft === 0 || distance === 0) ? 0 : ((new Date() - last) / timeLeft * distance);
   var diff = (distance > 0 ? Math.min(x, distance) : Math.max(x, distance));
   distance = distance - diff;
   scroll += diff;
   window.scrollTo(0, windowScrollDistance + scroll);

   last = new Date().getTime();

   if (last - start <= duration) {
    animate = (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
   }
   else {
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
     callback();
    }
   }
  };

  tick();
 };

 // Process the links.
 $links.each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var targetId = $this.attr('href').match(/#([^\?]+)/)[1];
  var target = document.getElementById(targetId);

  if (target) {
   $this.click(function (event) {
    var clickedLink = this;
    var scrollTargetOffset;
    var closeButtonAnimationDelay;

    event.preventDefault();

    // Is this link already expanded?
    if (isExpanded && activeLink === clickedLink) {
     // Close it.
     $closeButton.click();
    }
    // Otherwise, expand it.
    else {
     $links.removeClass(settings.elementActiveClass).filter($this).addClass(settings.elementActiveClass).parent('li').each(function () {
      var lastSibling = getLastSiblingInRow(this);
      activeRowChanged = lastSibling !== lastItemInActiveRow;
      if (activeRowChanged) {
       lastItemInActiveRow = lastSibling;
      }
      // If we are changing rows, replace spacer with secondary spacer.
      if (isExpanded && activeRowChanged) {
       $secondarySpacer.height($spacer.height());
       $spacer.height(0).replaceWith($secondarySpacer);
      }
      $(lastItemInActiveRow).after($spacer);
     });
     if (isExpanded && activeRowChanged) {
      $secondarySpacer.animate({height: 0}, settings.animationDuration, function () {
       $(this).detach();
      });
      $closeButton.removeClass(settings.elementActiveClass).hide();
     }
     scrollTargetOffset = ($secondarySpacer.position().top < $spacer.position().top ? $secondarySpacer.height() : 0);
     activeExpandedAreaTop = ($spacer.position().top - scrollTargetOffset);
     $expandingAreas.removeClass(settings.elementExpandedClass).hide().filter(target).each(function () {
       var $this = $(this);
       var autoHeight = $this.height();
       var autoOuterHeight = $this.outerHeight();
       var initialHeight = (isExpanded && activeExpandedAreaHeight && (activeRowChanged === false)) ? activeExpandedAreaHeight : 0;

       stopExpandedAreaMonitor();

       $spacer.animate({height: autoHeight + 'px'}, settings.animationDuration);

       $this.css({
        height: initialHeight + 'px',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: $spacer.position().top + 'px'
       }).show(0, function () {
        // Callback.
        if (typeof settings.onExpandBefore === 'function') {
         settings.onExpandBefore.call(this);
        }
       }).animate({
        height: autoHeight + 'px',
        top: activeExpandedAreaTop + 'px'
       }, settings.animationDuration, function () {
        $this.css({height: 'auto'}).addClass(settings.elementExpandedClass);

        // Set a timer to monitor changes to expanded area’s height.
        activeExpandedAreaHeight = $this.height();
        checkExpandedAreaResize = setInterval(function () {
         var activeExpandedAreaNewHeight = $this.height();
         if (activeExpandedAreaNewHeight !== activeExpandedAreaHeight) {
          activeExpandedAreaHeight = activeExpandedAreaNewHeight;
          syncExpandedAreaWithSpacer();
         }
        }, 1000);

        // Callback.
        if (typeof settings.onExpandAfter === 'function') {
         settings.onExpandAfter.call(this);
        }
       });

       // Scroll the page to bring the active link and preview into view.
       var scrollTargetTop = $(clickedLink).offset().top - scrollTargetOffset;
       var scrollTargetBottom = $this.offset().top + autoOuterHeight + 20 - scrollTargetOffset;
       scrollSectionIntoView(scrollTargetTop, scrollTargetBottom);
      });

     // Activate close button.
     closeButtonAnimationDelay = (isExpanded && activeRowChanged && ($this.parent().index() > $(activeLink).parent().index())) ? settings.animationDuration : (settings.animationDuration / 4);
     $closeButton.css({
       position: 'absolute',
       right: 0,
       top: activeExpandedAreaTop + 'px'
      }).delay(closeButtonAnimationDelay).fadeIn(settings.animationDuration, function () {
       $(this).addClass(settings.elementActiveClass);
      });

     // Set global variables.
     activeLink = this;
     activeExpandedArea = target;
     isExpanded = true;
    }
   });
  }
 });

 // Process the close button.
 $closeButton.appendTo(context).hide().click(function (event) {
  var $activeLink = $(activeLink);
  var activeLinkTopOffset = $activeLink.offset().top;
  var activeLinkBottomOffset = activeLinkTopOffset + $activeLink.outerHeight();

  event.preventDefault();

  // DOM manipulation and animations.
  $links.removeClass(settings.elementActiveClass);
  $expandingAreas.slideUp(settings.animationDuration).removeClass(settings.elementExpandedClass);
  $closeButton.removeClass('active').hide();
  $spacer.animate({height: 0}, settings.animationDuration, function () {
   $spacer.detach();
  });

  // Scroll the page to bring the active link into view.
  scrollSectionIntoView(activeLinkTopOffset, activeLinkBottomOffset);

  stopExpandedAreaMonitor();

  // Reset global variables.
  isExpanded = false;
  activeLink = false;
  activeExpandedArea = false;
 });

 /**
  * Stop monitoring size of expanded area.
  */
 var stopExpandedAreaMonitor = function () {
  if (checkExpandedAreaResize) {
   clearInterval(checkExpandedAreaResize);
  }
 };

 /**
  * Match preview and spacer in height and position.
  */
 var syncExpandedAreaWithSpacer = function () {
  if (activeExpandedArea && isExpanded) {
   $spacer.height($(activeExpandedArea).height());
   activeExpandedAreaTop = $spacer.position().top;
   $closeButton.add(activeExpandedArea).css({top: activeExpandedAreaTop + 'px'});
  }
 };

 /**
  * Place spacer in proper position within grid.
  */
 var positionSpacer = function () {
  var lastSibling;
  if (activeLink && lastItemInActiveRow && isExpanded) {
   // Remove spacer.
   $spacer.detach();
   lastSibling = getLastSiblingInRow($(activeLink).parent()[0]);
   // Reposition spacer, if necessary.
   if (lastItemInActiveRow !== lastSibling) {
    console.log(lastSibling);
    lastItemInActiveRow = lastSibling;
   }
   // Restore spacer.
   $(lastItemInActiveRow).after($spacer);
  }
 };

 // React to window resize.
 $(window).resize(function () {
  if (isExpanded) {
   positionSpacer();
   syncExpandedAreaWithSpacer();
  }
 });
};

// Create the jQuery plugin.
$.fn.expandingGrid = function (options) {
 return this.each(function () {
  expandingGrid(this, options);
 });
};

})(jQuery, window, document);

$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.expanding-grid').expandingGrid();
});
```

```css
// Basic styles.

body {
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #333;
 font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1.5;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 80em;
 overflow-y: scroll; // Permanent scroll bar.
 padding: 2em;
}

// Styles for our expanding grid.

$image-bg-color: orange;
$expanded-area-bg-color: #888;

.expanding-grid {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 .links {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 -1em;
  overflow: hidden; // Clearfix.
  padding: 1em 0;
  > li {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   float: left;
   padding: 1em;
   a {
    background: $image-bg-color;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 25% 1em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    &:hover {
     background: lighten($image-bg-color, 10%);
    }
    &.active {
     background: darken($image-bg-color, 10%);
     &:after {
      background-color: transparent;
      border-bottom: 0.375em solid $expanded-area-bg-color;
      border-left: 0.375em solid transparent;
      border-right: 0.375em solid transparent;
      bottom: -0.5em;
      content: '';
      height: 0;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -0.375em;
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
     }
    }
   }
   @media only screen and (max-width: 39.99em) {
    width: 50%;
    &:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
     clear: left;
    }
   }
   @media only screen and (min-width: 40em) and (max-width: 59.99em) {
    width: percentage(1/3);
    &:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
     clear: left;
    }
   }
   @media only screen and (min-width: 60em) {
    width: percentage(1/4);
    &:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
     clear: left;
    }
   }
  }
 }

 .spacer {
  background-color: $expanded-area-bg-color;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 1em;
 }

 .expanding-container {
  clear: both;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  &.expanded,
  &:target {
   display: block;
  }
 }

 .hentry {
  background: $expanded-area-bg-color;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 4em;
  overflow: hidden; // Clearfix.
  padding: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  .entry-image {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   float: right;
   margin-left: 1em;
   padding: 0.25em 0 0.52em 1em;
   text-align: center;
   width: 50%;
  }
  .entry-title {
   font-size: 1.5em;
  }
 }

 .close-button {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDIwIDIwIj48cGF0aCBzdHJva2U9IiNmZmYiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMiIgc3Ryb2tlLW1pdGVybGltaXQ9IjEwIiBkPSJNLjcuN2wxOCAxOG0tMTggMGwxOC0xOCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==) no-repeat scroll 50% 50% transparent;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 20px;
  will-change: opacity;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  &.active {
   transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }
  &:hover {
   opacity: 0.5;
  }
 }
}

// Style our simulated images.

.img-placeholder {
 background: $image-bg-color;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 4em;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1;
 padding: 25% 0.25em;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="expanding-grid">
 
 <ul class="links">
  <li><a href="#section1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section4">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section5">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section6">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section7">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section8">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section9">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section10">10</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section11">11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section12">12</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div id="section1" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">1</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum consequatur, culpa voluptate distinctio iure! Error saepe cumque molestiae deserunt nemo autem non amet, aliquam vitae nulla sit praesentium unde iusto.</p>
  </article>
 </div>

 <div id="section2" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">2</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati veniam aliquam eos eius blanditiis, facilis minus quod nostrum. Dolores recusandae doloremque quam consequatur consequuntur accusantium quos possimus inventore ratione reiciendis!</p>
  </article>
 </div>

 <div id="section3" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">3</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum consequatur, culpa voluptate distinctio iure! Error saepe cumque molestiae deserunt nemo autem non amet, aliquam vitae nulla sit praesentium unde iusto.</p>
  </article>
 </div>

 <div id="section4" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">4</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati veniam aliquam eos eius blanditiis, facilis minus quod nostrum. Dolores recusandae doloremque quam consequatur consequuntur accusantium quos possimus inventore ratione reiciendis!</p>
  </article>
 </div>

 <div id="section5" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">5</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum consequatur, culpa voluptate distinctio iure! Error saepe cumque molestiae deserunt nemo autem non amet, aliquam vitae nulla sit praesentium unde iusto.</p>
  </article>
 </div>

 <div id="section6" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">6</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati veniam aliquam eos eius blanditiis, facilis minus quod nostrum. Dolores recusandae doloremque quam consequatur consequuntur accusantium quos possimus inventore ratione reiciendis!</p>
  </article>
 </div>

 <div id="section7" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">7</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum consequatur, culpa voluptate distinctio iure! Error saepe cumque molestiae deserunt nemo autem non amet, aliquam vitae nulla sit praesentium unde iusto.</p>
  </article>
 </div>

 <div id="section8" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">8</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati veniam aliquam eos eius blanditiis, facilis minus quod nostrum. Dolores recusandae doloremque quam consequatur consequuntur accusantium quos possimus inventore ratione reiciendis!</p>
  </article>
 </div>
 
 <div id="section9" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">9</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum consequatur, culpa voluptate distinctio iure! Error saepe cumque molestiae deserunt nemo autem non amet, aliquam vitae nulla sit praesentium unde iusto.</p>
  </article>
 </div>

 <div id="section10" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">10</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati veniam aliquam eos eius blanditiis, facilis minus quod nostrum. Dolores recusandae doloremque quam consequatur consequuntur accusantium quos possimus inventore ratione reiciendis!</p>
  </article>
 </div>

 <div id="section11" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">11</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum consequatur, culpa voluptate distinctio iure! Error saepe cumque molestiae deserunt nemo autem non amet, aliquam vitae nulla sit praesentium unde iusto.</p>
  </article>
 </div>

 <div id="section12" class="expanding-container">
  <article class="hentry">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
   <div class="entry-image"><div class="img-placeholder">12</div></div>
   <p>Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati veniam aliquam eos eius blanditiis, facilis minus quod nostrum. Dolores recusandae doloremque quam consequatur consequuntur accusantium quos possimus inventore ratione reiciendis!</p>
  </article>
 </div>
</div>
```

The snippet doesn't work for some reason here but you can see it in action here (without spaces):
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/DanBoulet/pen/YXQBbZ)

Comment: You want your full grid to get 100% width? But the image you provided took 100% height not 100% width.

Comment: 100% height and width

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i'm understanding you completely but here is answer. 1 note, i've tried to use your setup as much as possible. If it were my project I would opt for rows and such:
To make your content 100% and 100% height you have to get the body to have 0 `padding`, and no `margin` and also 100% `width`:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll; // Permanent scroll bar.
}
```

Now we need to make the first row of the grid have `0 top padding` and every first element `0 left padding` and last element have `0 right padding`. I did this using the `:nth-child` psuedo selector:

```
   .links {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden; // Clearfix.

    > li {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        padding: 1em;   

        &:nth-child(-n+4){
            padding-top: 0;
        }
        &:nth-child(4){
                padding-right: 0;
            }
        &:nth-child(4n+1) {  /* or 4n+1 */
            padding-left: 0;
        background-color: green;   
    }
    &:nth-child(4n+4) {  /* or 4n+1 */
            padding-right: 0;
        background-color: pink;   
    }
```

Here is the pen that I made:[My pen](http://codepen.io/VeldMuijz/pen/RrPbpW)

There is one problem though your a elements in the middle (your second and third element of each row) is a different size since you use % to size them up.

I don't have more time to do this right now but I hope I steered you into a solution.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how I could make the grid flush with the bottom of the page as well?

Comment: Use `nth-last-child` like you use it for the first four with `nth-first-child`.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use 100vh, base on screen size it will change.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for - https://codepen.io/rupeshkumarrj/pen/jOYVxNg

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.links {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.links li {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="#section1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section5">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section6">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section7">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section8">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section9">9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section10">10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section11">11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section12">12</a></li>
    </ul>
```